# Correct user group and permissions for WordPress on Google Compute Engine

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, user-permissions

I'm running into user group and permission issues restoring a site to Google Compute Engine from the VaultPress backup solution; I'm being told it's related to permissions and the SSH user not being able to write new files.

Can you suggest what permission/ownership change I should make so that my local user can write and edit file changes within a WordPress instance, by default all directories and files within the site belong to the www-data user and group. Thank you for your time :)